# Context in Node.js module - How to access functions with reflection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Can anyone tell me, in which context functions are put, when created globally in modules?

I try to access functions via reflection. A simplified approach is shown below.

```
leaf.js:

function GlobalLeafFn(){
  console.log("2");
}

console.log("Fn in Leaf via this" + this["GlobalLeafFn"]);
console.log("Fn in Leaf via global" + global["GlobalLeafFn"]);
```

When executed directly with **node leaf.js** the function can be found.

But when including the module in another script with

```
require("./leaf.js");
```

they are not found.

I already realized, that best practice is to use custom namespaces.
But for curiosity I want to know: where are the functions referenced?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is a bit different from browser. Node.js has by default modules, every file is a module. Everything defined in the file as in your example, is private to that module. So you don't need namespaces in Node.js, because they are implicitly given via the module system.

in a Node.js module you have following scopes:

**the default private scope**

Here goes everything defined outside of a function with `var` or a function statement. It is the so called context.

**the global scope**

if you define something without `var` or assign it to a property on the `global` object. Also all built in types such as Array, Object, etc are here.

**the export scope**

everything defined with `module.exports =` or `exports.foo =` goes to this scope. this is what a user of the module can access from the outside. the public part. Initially the `this` variable in the module is bound to module.exports